# R paste html string with header

Tags: r, dplyr, paste

Can't find a satisfactory solution to a probably very simple problem.

I have a dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(date=c("a","a","a","a","b","b"),text=c("c","d","e","f","g","h"))
```

and I need string like that:

```
"<h4>date a </h4><br> c <br> d <br> e <br> f <br> <h4>date b </h4> <br> g <br> h"
```

Any hint would be highly apreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit clunky but you can try:

```
do.call(paste, list("<h4> date", unique(df$date), "</h4><br>", tapply(df$text, df$date, FUN =  paste, collapse = " <br> "), collapse = " "))

[1] "<h4> date a </h4><br> c <br> d <br> e <br> f <br> <h4> date b </h4><br> g <br> h"
```

Comment: Perfect! I prefer this solution to the solution of SebSta, because it is more flexible.

Comment: Unfortunately I still have a follow-up question: I would like to have '<h4> date b</h4>' in the first place, so the list should be in reverse order. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: ```rev()``` reverses the order of a vector. So you need to reverse both the unique call and the tapply call: ```do.call(paste, list("<h4> date", rev(unique(df$date)), "</h4><br>", rev(tapply(df$text, df$date, FUN =  paste, collapse = " <br> ")), collapse = " "))```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
 df <- data.frame(date=c("a","a","a","a","b","b"),text=c("c","d","e","f","g","h"), stringsAsFactors = F)


 p1 <- paste("<h4>date", unique(df$date)[1], "</h4><br>", paste(df$text[df$date=="a"], collapse = " <br> "), "<br>")
 p2 <- paste("<h4>date", unique(df$date)[2], "</h4><br>", paste(df$text[df$date=="b"], collapse = " <br> "))

 paste(p1,p2)
```